# How to form a recurrence for findng the height of a weight balanced binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree

A weight balanced tree is a binary tree in which for each node, the no. of nodes in the left subtree is atleast half and at most twice the no. of nodes in the right sub tree. So how to approach for forming a recurrence for finding the height of this weight balanced binary tree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only full binary trees can be weight-balanced. Let `H(n)` be the maximum height of a weight-balanced binary tree with exactly `n` *interior* nodes (so, `2*n+1` nodes). The base case

```
H(0) = 0
```

is obvious. The recurrence

```
             floor((4*n/3-1)/2)
H(n) = 1 +           max          max(H(l), H(n-1-l))     for all n > 0
           l=ceiling((2*n/3-1)/2)
```

follows from the recurrence for height and the fact that, given `n-1` interior nodes that are not the root, we must distribute them between the left (`l`) and the right (`n-1-l`) subtrees, subject to the weight-balance criterion. (There are `2*n` interior and exterior nodes to distribute; the most unbalanced split possible is one-third/two-thirds; a full binary tree with `k` nodes has `(k-1)/2` interior nodes.)

Let's conjecture that `H(n)` is nondecreasing and write a new recurrence

```
H'(0) = 0
H'(n) = 1 + H'(floor(2*n/3-1/2))     for all n > 0.
```

The point of the new recurrence is that, if it is in fact nondecreasing, then `H(n) = H'(n)`, by an strong induction proof that involves simplifying the maxes in the other recurrence. In fact, we can prove by induction without solving `H'(n)` that it is, in fact, nondecreasing, so this simplification is fine.

As for solving `H'(n)`, I'll wave my hands and tell you that [Akra--Bazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) applies (alternatively, the Master Theorem Case 2 if you want to play fast and loose with the `floor`), yielding the asymptotic bound `H'(n) = Theta(log n)`.